# How do I know if my dev environment and application is Ruby of JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I installed, both JRuby and Ruby, and also Rails.  To create a new application I just type

```
rails new app_name
```

And an application gets created.  So is this application Ruby or JRuby?

Comment: I believe it can run under both of them. There is no difference with which Ruby version it was created

Comment: It's Ruby. JRuby and Ruby are different implementations of the same language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could detect your ruby version by running `ruby -v`.

However, I would highly suggest you use [RVM](https://rvm.io) to manage your ruby versions if you can. This will allow you to quickly switch between full Ruby environments that are completely isolated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RVM, just go into the rails app directory, and type
`ruby -v`
on the command prompt, you will get to know which ruby you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Within Ruby, you can check the `RUBY_ENGINE` constant ("ruby" in normal MRI Ruby, "jruby" in JRuby).

Unfortunately, this constant is not defined in older versions of Ruby, so you should check with `defined?(RUBY_ENGINE)` if it exsits.

Answer (score 1):

Executing 'rails' command using JRuby produces the same "pure" Rails project as pure (aka MRI) Ruby does.

MRI Ruby application "becomes" JRuby application when you run it with the JRuby interpreter instead of the pure Ruby one. The is a runtime difference.

Of course your bare Rails application won't work properly with JRuby interpreter until you configure it to use JRuby gems (JDBC). Please note also that it is possible to create Rails application that can properly run both under JRuby and MRI Ruby.